# Update single record in mongodb using express and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I want to update a single record by _id in a collection in mongoDB.

UPDATE:  I changed the res to req (thanks!) and implemented the db.ObjectId() around the objectId I am passing in and now I get a 500 internal server error.

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("54d5296711436278137af74b"),
    "username" : "alex",
    "email" : "alex@gmail",
    "fullname" : "alex man",
    "age" : "15",
    "location" : "minneap",
    "gender" : "mal"
```

This is my ajax call from the client.

```
    $.ajax({
                    type: 'PUT',
                    data: updatedUser,
                    url: '/users/updateuser/' + globalUserID,
                    dataType: 'JSON'
                }).done(function(response){
```

This is the routing code.

```
/*
* PUT to updateuser
*/
router.put('/updateuser/:id', function(req, res) {
var db = req.db;
var userToUpdate = req.params.id;
db.collection('userlist').update(
{ _id: userToUpdate},
   req.body,
    function(err, result){
    res.send(
        (err === null) ? {msg: ''} : {msg: err}
    );
   });
});
```

I get a 200 response back but my record is not updated. What is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: res.send will always send  200. Because it returns either '' or the error with status code 200 OK. If you have an error you should do res.status(500).send('Something broke!');

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make sure you're turning the `string` _id into an `ObjectId`.

Also, you were using `res`.body instead of `req`.body.

```
router.put('/updateuser/:id', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var userToUpdate = req.params.id;
    db.collection('userlist').update({ _id: ObjectId(userToUpdate)}, req.body, function (err, result) {
        res.send(
            (err === null) ? {msg: ''} : {msg: err}
        );
    });
});
```

Different drivers use a different method to create an ObjectId:

- mongoDB native driver: new ObjectId(`idString`);
- mongoJS: db.ObjectId(`idString`);
- mongoSkin: toObjectID(`idString`);
- mongoose: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(`idString`);

Comment: I implemented those changes and now get a 500 error.  It has something to do with the db.ObjectId() method but I do not know what it is.

Comment: I'm assuming that db is your mongoDB driver, so it should work. db.ObjectId() might not be a method of created an object id for your database driver. It is for mongojs, but if you are using another mongo driver, db.ObjectId() might not work. Also, what is the error stack received?

Comment: you can try new ObjectID(`idString`); this is the method the native mongoDB uses. Mongoose you use mongoose.Types.ObjectId(`string`);

Comment: My db is the "mongo.db(url)" database connection.  The error stack from the node app doesn't say much.                                                                PUT /users/updateuser/54d3ba6cfe49c07c04733fac 500 42.412 ms

Comment: I am using mongoskin fyi

Comment: Also, one more thing, make sure `(req.params.id.length === 22)`, otherwise you might kill your application if someone sends an id that isn't an actual id, or is `undefined`

Comment: MongoSkin uses toObjectID(`idString`);

Comment: I am going to accept this answer because of all the good information, but I am still having issues.

Comment: Once you successfully update a document, the `err, res` response will look something like `null, { "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 }`. just `console.log()` the heck out of everything.

Answer (score 1):

It should be req.body, not res.body

```
db.collection('userlist').update(
{ _id: userToUpdate},
   res.body -> should be req.body
```